# If pictures are worth a thousand words then why are we so adverse to allowing emojis in titles?

Tags: discussion, moderation, title

If you have a title like `something + something`  you can infer the intent of the question. So why is that that we have people trying to tell me to keep my emotions out of my questions when clearly it conveyed useful information even if not explicitly? It seems petty to me that we can't discern between an abuse of something and just common use.

I think it conveys a hyperbolic authoritarianism that to me is just as petty as any complaint of the use of the thing in question in the first place.

To say that it does not provide value to the question is subjective and thus there should be less emphasis on correcting the use of emojis unless you can observe a clear abuse of the emojis. In which case if abuse of the emojis looks to be the case then it is then an issue should be raised at on per case issue just like any abuse case. Let's not stifle others communication because the fact is we are still human beings and there there is more than one way to communicate. After all is that not what we are really after more effective communication?

Comment: How does the overly dramatic  convey _any_ useful information? It just looks cringey.

Comment: If someone decided to spray emoji's all over a question&answer to my problem, I'd look like this:

Comment: A picture speaks a thousand words exactly because it can be interpreted so many different ways. The crying face emoji can mean so many different things when read by users from all over the world; you're much better off using your words as to not get misinterpreted. (Hint: The tone that that emoji sets off it **my** head is whiny teenager that's not worth listening to)

Comment:   ✍ “”   

Comment: You also say that preventing emojis is hyperbolic and petty. Honestly, I can't think of anything more hyperbolic and petty than emojis (including my hyperbole just now).

Comment: From your profile, I can see that this question stemmed from an edit to [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53907939/minicssextractplugin-loader-npm-packages-relative-css-url-paths) entitled "MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader + NPM packages + Relative CSS URL paths ". Please explain what that emoji adds to the question. What information does it convey which is useful for someone answering it?

Comment: I did try adding emoji to my source code.  It looked nice and friendly to me, but my compiler generated 23 pages of error messages.  Would you like to help?

Comment: @MartinJames compilers these days are still rather toxic. I wonder why anti-SO movements don't focus on that instead.

Comment: This suggestion = 

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I think it's more  than .

Comment: @TemaniAfif totally but I think [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IALOm.jpg) explains it the best.

Comment: @PaulCrovella, I'm going to take a stab at what your emoji sentence reads: "I am sad to write 'Your question was so [poop emoji]' that my fall from my chair was felt around the world, and that makes me sad."   Was I close?

Comment: Do remember our goal: to build a highly searchable, low noise to signal ratio library of good programming topics that will be useful for future readers. I find that using emojis make your content less clear, more ambiguous, and less searchable than using words. With that in mind, care to explain why you still think they are a good addition?

Comment: `If you have a title like something + something  you can infer the intent of the question` Wait what? No, not at all. Does that mean "those something's make me cry"? Or rather "one something + one different something that is crying"? Or maybe "that something plus that something is a product that is crying"? This is like super ambiguous, how can it be clear?

Comment: I think "something + somethingelse " means "I cry when I see how complete @#$# use *something* and *somethingelse* together." While I frequently feel the same, expressing it in a title (or comments) would be considered "rude and not welcoming".

Answer (score 63):

> If you have a title like `something + something`  you can infer the intent of the question.

OK, what *exactly* is the intent that should be inferred from such a question?

Are we supposed to infer that you're crying? That you're a person who enjoys crying over their programming problems? That something in the question title made you sad? That the problem is so difficult it made you cry?

And most important of all... why should the reader *care about any of that?*

Your emotions are of no relevance to the problem you are presenting in your question. That's why we cull out things like "Hi" and "Thanks" and other chatty stuff. It's noise, and we want a site that is free of such clutter and is impersonal.

In 10 years, when someone else has the same problem as you did, they *will not care* if it made you cry. They care that they can quickly identify that their problem is the same as yours and find a good solution to it. That's all. That's what we're here to create.

Emoticons do not in any way, shape, or form help in creating our easily searchable database of problems and solutions. That is not "subjective".

But there is something which *is* subjective. This:

> MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader + NPM packages + Relative CSS URL paths

This is the original title of [the post that started this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53907939/minicssextractplugin-loader-npm-packages-relative-css-url-paths).

In a comment, you said:

> my simple was not simplely my emotions on the matter but rather an indication that the combinations of words I had in my title indicated that they are incompatible by default using far less words to describe the intent of my question.

I certainly didn't take that from your original form of the title. Now, that may be because I personally ignore anything that is not informational content (ie: emojis). But even when I look at the crying emoji, my take-away is not "these things are incompatible". It's more "I'm sad because of these things". Why you are sad is not presented.

What you're not understanding here is that, just because you have an idea in your head of what you want to communicate, does not mean you have successfully *communicated it*. You believe that the "combination of words" combined with a crying emoji will naturally translate to "these things are incompatible". But that all depends on the thinking of the person who reads them. Thinking which you are not privy to and have limited control over.

Had you used the words "these things are not compatible by default", there would be no question. So long as the reader understood English, they would have an understanding of what you were trying to communicate. Words provide (usually) unambiguous informational content; their meaning is typically objective. Emojis are usually subjective, open to interpretation and thus are not a precise form of communication.

Or to put it another way, it is not the reader's fault that they do not interpret your crying emoji as "these things are not compatible by default"; it is *your fault* for not communicating that clearly.

We want communication with words on this site. If others want different kinds of communication, there are forums and other more personal sites that they can visit.

Comment: I think that last part is the most important. SE in general makes a big deal about being an accessible repository of useful information. Emojis are next to imposible to search.

Answer (score 33):

Since I played a role in that; let me post the comments we exchanged under [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53907939/minicssextractplugin-loader-npm-packages-relative-css-url-paths) where I edited the title in order to remove the unnecessary emoji:

[image: comments screenshot]

<sup>*(There is a missing comment at the beginning by the OP that has been deleted since)*</sup>

---

I have nothing more to add to what I already said in these comments; and the Nicol Bolas answer concurs with what I already said (even the reference to the removal of greetings in posts).

I hope you will be convinced that it's not about *you* and there is nothing against *you*, it's all about the community and the content.

Comment: That rude "putting your fingers in other people's food" response for your giving a friendly reminder about keeping questions focused makes me 

Answer (score 10):

Honestly, I can't think of any singular reason that an emoji could be relevant to the content you're inquiring about *unless* it is specifically about parsing emojis -- Which just so happens to be a pretty common question when it comes to regular expressions and string parsing.

The idea of your distinction between trying to convey "this is making me sad" vs "these things are incompatible" can in no way shape or form be determined from a simple emoticon -- I think saying "these are incompatible" is a much more explicit way of conveying the idea. Especially when you're speaking to programmers who's jobs are based around being as explicit as possible. I won't repeat much of what has already been said, but I just thought I'd add the notion of cases where it *would* be accepted and makes complete sense to have them in the post.